# Android Custom Button Drawable XML File

Tags: android, xml, custom-controls

I recently discovered that you can describe an Android custom drawable in an XML file, which you can then use with a button (and other View, I guess), and this inspired me to ask this question:

Does anyone know (or know where I can find) an XML file that precisely describes the exact default button that shows up in an Android application if you don't change a single detail.

It seems to me, that would be a very helpful starting point.

Thanks,
R.

Comment: The default button uses png 9patch files rather than being defined as shapes in an xml. The only xml file that does exist for it is the Button selector.

Comment: Ah yes, I should've remembered...  But perhaps there's an XML approximation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Android Views, like Button, and its selector XML files are available in resource folder of particular Android platform.

For example,
\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable folders.

These drawables and XML files are accessible in our application code, using 'android.R'. 
For example: android.R.drawable.btn_check

Comment: Well, THAT is certainly something I'll need to remember, but not really an answer to my question.  I was trying to find the precise definition of a button view so that I could very easily change a single detail (or a small number of details) to get a SLIGHTLY rather than radically different looking button.  But thanks again for the insight into the repository of existing graphics!!

Answer (score 4):

//this is an nice tutor for gradient

This time, all those gradients are created programmatically which gives you total control of the button and the gradient!

[link here:](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/08/even-more-gradient-buttons-for-android/)

[image]

Comment: I cant post the screen shot in comment so I put that in answer.

Comment: That site looks like some very good information, but there's very little XML there.  I've been reminded the default Android button view is a nine-patch, but I still think it can't be too difficult to set up an XML approximation.  Of course, now it looks like I'm trying to get the community to solve my problems for me.  Oh well, thanks for the info.

Comment: The author of that gradient tutorial also shows how to build them using XML in [his first post](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/) and links to a demo app in [his second](http://www.dibbus.com/2012/08/more-buttons/).